# Docker - cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists

Tags: ubuntu, docker, volumes

I'm trying to build a data container for my application in Docker. I run this command to expose some volumes:

```
docker run --name svenv.nl-data -v /etc/environment -v /etc/ssl/certs -v /var/lib/mysql -d svenv/svenv.nl-data
```

The problem is that i get this error from this command:

```
Error response from daemon: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/aefa66cf55357e2e1e4f84c2d4d2d03fa2375c8900fe3c0e1e6bc02f13e54d05/etc/environment
```

If I understand the Docker documentation correctly. Creating volumes for single files is supported. So I don't understand why I get this error.

Is there somebody who can explain this to me? I'm running Docker 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: have you solved it in some way ?

Comment: Turned out some file cannot be overwritten by docker irrc. It think /etc/environment is reserved.

Answer (score 11):

You should use:

```
-v /etc/environment:/etc/environment
```

instead of:

```
-v /etc/environment
```

The former maps container volume to the host volume. 
The latter tries to create a new volume at `/etc/environment` and fails since this directory already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are under Linux, run the following code

```
docker run -it --rm -v /local_dir:/image_root_dir/mount_dir image_name
```

Here is some detail:

```
-it: interactive terminal 
--rm: remove container after exit the container
-v: volume or say mount your local directory to a volume
```

Since the mount function will 'cover' the directory in your image, your should always make a new directory under your images root directory.

Visit official documentation [Use bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

`cannot mount volume over existing file` might also mean that you're trying to mount a **folder** from the host to a **file** in the container which is a logical bug.

If so, wrap the file in the container in a folder and mount that folder instead of the file.

Comment: uh exactly what happened to me... in the end I used dot as a current folder and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I guess because you are not mounting a file but instead declaring a mount. Try this notation instead: `-v <full path to a file you want to overwrite the target with>:/etc/environment`

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the file with an other file. What i'm trying to achieve is to mark the /etc/environment as volume so it can be used by another container using --volumes-from. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to remove the image, and rebuild. Not a good solution, but it was what worked for me.