# Failure when restoring Docker container to another Docker host

Tags: docker

I created a tar file of my container using the following method.

On the first or source Docker host:

```
docker commit -p  78727078a04b  jenkins
docker save -o ~/jenkins.tar jenkins
```

Then on the new Docker host (it's a different machine)

```
docker load -i ~/jenkins.tar
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins
```

However, I got this error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e668ec2b2a563f692e4511352a0db2989791281cc8d13f04f36f02106ceebb0c/merged/run/docker.sock.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual practice is to not try to "move" or "save" or "export" or "commit" containers.  Just create a new container on the new machine.

For this to work you need to store all of the critical data your container needs outside the container.  The [Jenkins image documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md) discusses this.  It has a strong recommendation for using named volumes, which are harder to manage in several ways; the [Docker documentation on backing up named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) is relevant to this.

I'll assume you've created a named volume to hold the content.  If you haven't, [the Jenkins Dockerfile declares a `VOLUME`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L30) so there should be an anonymous volume holding the Jenkins home directory.  I'd look for its volume ID using `docker volume ls` or `docker inspect` and try using that.

```sh
# when you initially started Jenkins; copied from
# https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md
docker run \
  -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
  -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
  jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

You need to export the data from the volume.  (`docker stop` Jenkins might be a good idea first.)  You can use a temporary container to do this:

```sh
docker run \
  --rm \
  -v jenkins_home:/jenkins_home \
  -v $PWD:/export \
  -w /jenkins_home \
  busybox \
  tar cf /export/jenkins_home.tar .
gzip jenkins_home.tar
scp jenkins_home.tar.gz elsewhere:
```

Now you've gotten the data the container needs on to the remote host.  You need to recreate the data volume:

```sh
ssh elsewhere
gunzip jenkins_home.tar.gz
docker run \
  --rm \
  -v jenkins_home:/jenkins_home \
  -v $PWD:/import \
  -w /jenkins_home \
  busybox \
  tar xf /import/jenkins_home.tar .
```

Now the remote host has a volume named `jenkins_home` that has a copy of the exported data, and you can run the same Jenkins command you initially ran

```sh
ssh elsewhere
docker run \
  -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
  -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
  jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

This approach keeps the application and its data separate.  Since you're still using an unmodified upstream image, if there's ever a security issue and you need to upgrade Jenkins, you can `docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts` to get a newer version and restart the container.

`docker commit` is almost never a best practice.  Say you do need to update Jenkins; if you committed an image as in the question, you need to remember exactly what you did to create the image and repeat it, but the nature of a committed image is that there's no record of this.  If a custom image is useful for your application, write a Dockerfile for it and commit it to source control.  Also note that `docker commit` doesn't include volume content and the actual data you want to preserve is always in a volume (possibly anonymous) so the approach you're proposing in the question won't bring across the data you need anyways.

Comment: OK, I will try this today. Thank you.

Comment: Question. Why do I have to create a container to extract the tar file if I can extract it manually? One thing I see why we want to do that is preserve ownership and not use the local account where I'll be running `tar xf ....`

Comment: I got it working. I used --volumes-from {container} to create a tar backup then also used --volumes-from on the new container on the other docker_host to extract it. Then I followed your jenkins:lts

Comment: You can’t directly read or write to or from a named volume from the host, so you need to unpack the tar file inside a container on the target system to get its contents into a named volume there.

Comment: I was able to extract my backup.tar from the host machine. It's a regular tar file. However, I deleted it again and extracted it within the container.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing to provide volume which docker image expect here, start this with a mounting volume `-v` on expected location in the container.

not exact but for reference: [Docker - cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903621/docker-cannot-mount-volume-over-existing-file-file-exists])

Comment: This is how I remember I created the container last year - https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/ specifically the command I executed before was `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins`. I didn't specify any volume back then.

Comment: I just tried this command, I still got the same error message: `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v $home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins`

Comment: I still believe there is issue with your volume mounting, 
what is in $home, is there anything you have set as variable?

Comment: I meant $HOME and not $home since I just typed my previous response and copy+pasted the command. I'll redo it using the above instructions given by David Maze.